# AWS access policy to prevent elastic beanstalk configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, policy

We have a few elastic beanstalk applications and want to set up users that can see the events, status and logs for those applications in the AWS console. They should however not be able to even see the configuration. Is this possible? If I try to include ALL the actions apart from `DescribeConfigurationSettings` then that user cannot view the environment at all. So it appears that I have to use `Describe*` to allow the user to even access the environment.
Do I have to make them use the `eb cli` to fetch the logs or is there away to construct a policy so that they can view an environment but basically can not access the `Configuration` part of the environment

Comment: Can you stream logs to CloudWatch logs as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.envhealth.html) and [instance logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html#AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.streaming), and just let your users access CW logs only?

Comment: The users have full cloudwatch access but they still cannot run `eb logs` or `eb logs --stream`. But do you mean that I should stream them and store them somewhere locally and they access that instead?